# Does Linq OrderBy Not Sort Original Collection?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq To Sql as my database layer for the first time and I have run into an issue.  Basically, I have a form that allows users to create predefined jobs.  A predefined job can have many predefined job items.  For example, a predefined job might be something like an oil change.  The predefined job items would be oil, labor, etc.  In my database PredefinedJobs is a table and PredefinedJobItems is another table with a foreign key back to PredefinedJobs.  I have a form for adding predefined jobs that has the Linq-to-Sql class backing the form as a class variable.  There is a ListView on the form that displays all of the jobs items.  A new feature has required me to track the position of an item in the ListView.  For example, if my item ListView looks like below, note the order:

```
Qty          Name          Desc          ItemOrder
4            Oil           Penzoil       0
1            Labor                       1
```

Because the items are added via a child form I do not want to provide access to the ListView.  So, I created the method below in an attempt to both create the ItemOrder and sort the collection on the PredefinedJob Linq to Sql object.  It does not appear that the OrderBy function on the List actually sorts the collection on the PredefinedJob.  What would be the best way to maintain order on the Linq to Sql collection (i.e. PredefinedJob.fkJobItems)?  Or, would it be better to just pass a reference to my ListView into the child form that adds the items to the jobs where I have access to the selectedIndex?

```
    private SortAndOrderItems(List<PredefinedJobsItem> items)
    {
        var nextItemOrderNumber = items.Max(max => max.ItemOrder) + 1;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.ItemOrder == null)
            {
                item.ItemOrder = nextItemOrderNumber;
                nextItemOrderNumber++;
            }
        }
        items.OrderBy(i => i.ItemOrder).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`OrderBy` creates a new query, that will, when executed, not alter your original list.

Why not just the [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method of the `List`?

```
items.Sort((a, b) => a.ItemOrder.CompareTo(b.ItemOrder));
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply.  Will the Sort method of the List sort the actual collection in memory (i.e. collection of items on the Linq object)?

Comment: Yes, the method will sort the list in-place.

Comment: Excellent, I appreciate the help.  I'm slowly starting to get the hang of this.  Sometimes, it is the simple things that cost the most time.  BTW, do you know of any good web resources for beginners on Lambda expressions?  I tried reading the documentation on MSDN and it is pretty hard to understand for a beginner.

Comment: @Grasshopper Yeah, that's true! :-) I really recommend [C# in Depth](http://manning.com/skeet2/). It is a book and not a website, but it is totally worth it.

Comment: Okay, something that I left out is that the method above is called by converting an EntitySet to a List.  This will work for a list but, it will not work for the EntitySet: job.fkItems (where job is a PredefinedJob Linq Entity and fkItems is set of PredefinedJobItems).  Any suggestions on how I might sort the EntitySet?

Comment: You should use OrderBy to sort the EntitySet, before calling ToList(). In that case, we're talking about yet another behind-the-scenes subtlety called Queryable Linq; what the Linq methods do depends on exactly what they're called on. For an EntitySet (an IQueryable), the method won't actually run any code to sort it (like calling OrderBy does on an IEnumerable like a List), but will instead create an Expression that will be translated by the Entity Framework to the appropriate SQL Order By clause of the retrieval query.

Comment: That's the greatest power, and one of the flaws, of the Linq library; the same code does similar things on any conceptual "collection" of records, so you don't have to know exactly what that collection is (or even *where* it is). The flaw is that to make it work properly, you *do* have to know what you are calling the methods on, so that you can chain the methods in the proper order to produce the desired result efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for **[`List<>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)**

```
class Cmp : IComparer<PredefinedJobsItem>
{
    public int Compare(PredefinedJobsItem x, PredefinedJobsItem y)
    {
        return x.ItemOrder.CompareTo(y.ItemOrder);
    }
}


var comparison = new Cmp();
items.Sort(comparison);
```